# read text from edit control

Tags: c++, winapi, controls, win32gui

I want to read the text which the user has typed in a Edit control.
after entering the text and pressing the button, I want to get the text and add it as an item into a comboBox.
this is what I am doing in `WM_COMMAND` of the parent dialog:

```
case WM_COMMAND:

    if(HIWORD(wParam) == BN_CLICKED)
    {
        if ((HWND)lParam == Button[0])
        {



                int len = GetWindowTextLengthW(Button[2]) + 1;
                GetWindowTextW(Button[2], text, len);
                SendMessage(Button[1],(UINT) CB_ADDSTRING,(WPARAM) 0,(LPARAM) text);

                }
        }


    return 0;
```

but things goes wrong, sometime I get `NULL` in the "text" variable, sometimes just the first character of the string the user has entered and sometime weird ASCII like characters. what am I doing wron? any ideas ?

Comment: How is `Button[2]` initialized? And you should probably be using `SendMessageW`.

Comment: button[2] contains the handle of the edit box when it created by createWindow `Button[2] = CreateWindowW(
  L"edit", NULL,
  WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE|WS_OVERLAPPED|WS_BORDER,
  windowWidth - (windowWidth), windowHeigh,windowWidth ,windowHeight, handlW, (HMENU)ID_EDIT,instnc, NULL);`

Comment: Apologies, I meant to say `text` >.>

Comment: it is a global `LPWSTR`

Comment: `SendMessageW` did no effect. the `text` was defined like `LPWSTR text;` and when I did this `LPWSTR text = L"myText"; it always ad `myText` into comboBox no matter what user entered in edit control

Comment: You need to allocate space to hold the text. All you have is a pointer pointing to some unknown location and are trying to write into that.

Comment: I allocated this way `memset(&text,0,len);` but still I get `NULL`

Comment: Again, you're just writing 0s into an uninitialized pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allocate memory for the string. Here's how one would expect to do it in C++03:

```
std::vector<wchar_t> str(len);
GetWindowTextW(Button[2], &str[0], str.size());
SendMessageW(Button[1], CB_ADDSTRING, 0, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&str[0]));
```

Comment: you nailed it. thank you so much. how can I be expert on this like you ? this problem takes me too long, although I work with c++ most of the time.

Comment: @user667222, Go through a [book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) on C++ and browse through new SO questions a lot? Aside from doing things, that's pretty much my story. The winapi aspect is mostly experience, and a decent part Old New Thing.